# How to check user is logged in or not with phone authentication using firebase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Here, I'm authenticated through the phone number with OTP code using firebase but 
after login succeeded, it navigated through home page but when I click on back
it drags me login Screen.

here, the code I have tried, but it doesn't work

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   isSignedIn();
  }


  void isSignedIn() async {
    this.setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

  firebaseAuth.currentUser().then((user){
    if(user !=null){
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
    }else{
       verifyPhone();
    }
  });
  this.setState(() {
    isLoading = false;
  });

  }
```

Method for getting OTP code

```
Future<void> verifyPhone()async{
    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieval=(String verId){
      this.verificationId=verId;
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent=(String verId, [int forceCodeResend]){
      this.verificationId=verId;
      smsCodeDialog(context).then((value){
        print("Signed in");
      });
    };



    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted = (AuthCredential credential) {
     print("verified");
   };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verfifailed=(AuthException exception){
      print("${exception.message}");
    };

    await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
     phoneNumber: this.phoneNo,
     codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieval,
     codeSent: smsCodeSent,
     timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
     verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
     verificationFailed: verfifailed
    );
  }
```

here the dialog box for sign in  with OTP code

```
Future<bool> smsCodeDialog(BuildContext context){
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return new AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Enter sms Code'),
          content: TextField(
            onChanged: (value){
              this.smsCode=value;
            },
          ),
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
              child: Text("Done"),
              onPressed: (){
                firebaseAuth.currentUser().then((user){
                  if(user !=null){
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
                  }else{
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    signIn();
                  }
                });
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

method for Sign in with phone number

```
signIn()async{
    AuthCredential credential= PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCode
    );
    await  firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user){
       Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
         print('signed in with phone number successful: user -> $user');
    }).catchError((onError){
      print(onError);
    });
  }
`
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work ? " Do you get any exception ? Did you try to debug to see until what line the code works ?

Comment: What is the error? @Shruti

Comment: Sorry, there was an exception with my android build Gradle and I thought that something wrong in my code. sorry for wasting your precious time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome **Shruti Ramnandan Sharma** in Stackoverflow and Flutter dev.

Your code seems to working fine with me, I coded for you a one page dart that can test you the whole code with fixing your problem with going back to Login or VerifyPhone page.

> Note: I changed your order of code in `verifyPhone()` method.
>
> And Changed `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');` to
>
> `Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
>                           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeRoute()));`

The whole code here

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(VerifyPhoneRoute());

class VerifyPhoneRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VerifyPhoneRouteState createState() {
    return _VerifyPhoneRouteState();
  }
}

class _VerifyPhoneRouteState extends State<VerifyPhoneRoute> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String verificationId;
  String phoneNo = "Your number here";
  String smsCode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isSignedIn();
  }

  void isSignedIn() async {
    this.setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    firebaseAuth.currentUser().then((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeRoute()),
        );
      } else {
        verifyPhone();
      }
    });
    this.setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  Future<void> verifyPhone() async {
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
        (AuthCredential credential) {
      print("verified");
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verifyFailed = (AuthException exception) {
      print("${exception.message}");
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResend]) {
      this.verificationId = verId;
      smsCodeDialog(context).then((value) {
        print("Signed in");
      });
    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieval = (String verId) {
      this.verificationId = verId;
    };

    await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: this.phoneNo,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieval,
        codeSent: smsCodeSent,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verifyFailed);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter Inapp Plugin by dooboolab'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Verify"),
              onPressed: () {
                verifyPhone();
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> smsCodeDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Enter sms Code'),
            content: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                this.smsCode = value;
              },
            ),
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                child: Text("Done"),
                onPressed: () {
                  firebaseAuth.currentUser().then((user) {
                    if (user != null) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeRoute()),
                      );
                    } else {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      signIn();
                    }
                  });
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  signIn() async {
    AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);
    await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeRoute()),
      );
      print('signed in with phone number successful: user -> $user');
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
  }
}

class HomeRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeRouteState createState() {
    return _HomeRouteState();
  }
}

class _HomeRouteState extends State<HomeRoute> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter Inapp Plugin by dooboolab'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Welcome There."),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code works fine with me. So if there's any problem happened with you again, don't be hesitate to comment on this answer. And if this answered your question and solve your problem, please make it as answer.

Comment: thanks, but there was an exception with my android build Gradle and I thought, something wrong in my code, and it got solved and working fine.

Comment: Thank you, May I ask you a question regarding flutter?

Comment: Sure you can. Please contact me on [LinkedIn](https://LinkedIn.com/in/ShadyBoshra2012) because comments it's not the right place to discussions.

Comment: Okay, I have sent you request

Answer (score 0):

Use method below by pass **verificationID** come from API firebase when code sent and **code** enter by user,  so if method return **FirebaseUser** the code is correct if return **null** the code enter by user is not correct

```
Future<FirebaseUser> getUserFromCodePhone(String code, String verificationID) async {
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verificationID, smsCode: code);
    try {
      AuthResult result = await mAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

      FirebaseUser currentUser = await mAuth.currentUser();
      if (currentUser != null && result.user.uid == currentUser.uid) {
        return currentUser;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (_) {}

    return null;
  }
```

> **How it work ?** : when use signInWithCredential method if code passed to
>   AuthCredential  is false then the method will throw PlatformException 
>   so out from try block and return null